# Implication from an equality in terms of expectations for uniqueness proof

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, nonlinear-optimization

I have shown that a solution to a nonlinear equation exists, and I am trying to show it is unique. Let *Y* > 0 be a continuous non-constant random variable, and $a_1$, $a_2$ real parameters. I have determined that if

$${E(Y^{a_1+1})\over E(Y^{a_1})}={E(Y^{a_2+1})\over E(Y^{a_2})}\Rightarrow a_1=a_2$$

then the solution is unique. But I have not been able to make much progress in establishing whether the implication is correct, or whether it would be correct under some weak assumptions about *Y* (beyond finite mean and variance). If it helps, *Y* may be assumed to have finite support and the parameters may be assumed to be positive.

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One simple case is where Y is a,b or c with probability p,q or r, and a1=0, a2=2.  Then the equation reduces to:  pq(a+b)(a-b)^2 + pr(a+c)(a-c)^2 + qr(b+c)(b-c)^2 = 0, so a=b=c.  This makes me think that the implication holds, and I suspect that some inequality will prove that nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid and non-constant with pdf $p$.  Replace $a_1$ and $a_2$ by $a$ and $b$, and assume $a>b$. Then the equation is
$$\frac{E[X^{a+1}]}{E[X^{a}]} = 
\frac{E[Y^{b+1}]}{E[Y^{b}]}$$

\begin{align}
0
&=E[X^{a+1}]E[Y^b]-E[X^a]E[Y^{b+1}]\\
&=E[X^{a+1}Y^b-X^a Y^{b+1}]\\
&= \iint (x-y)\,x^ay^b\, p(x)\,p(y)\, dx\, dy\\
& =\iint_{x>y} \left((x-y)\,x^ay^b+(y-x)\,y^ax^b\right)p(x)\,p(y)\, dx\, dy\\
& = \iint_{x>y} (x-y)(x^{a-b} - y^{a-b})\, x^b y^b p(x)\,p(y)\, dx\, dy
\end{align}
An integral of positive quantities can not be 0, so this is a contradiction.  Thus $a=b$, which is the same as $a_1=a_2$.